# Business logic in oracle database or in PHP application

Tags: php, oracle

I have a question for people who have experience working with Oracle and PHP. Please this is not to open a meaningless debate. I just want to make sure everything is considered correctly in my system.
I am working on a project in which there are thousands of users, divided into groups and sub groups. Each group has its different access rights and each subgroup has its own privileges.
I need to have your opinion about these two approaches:

1. Implementing access rights and privileges in PHP with one big
   application user(oracle account),(I am clueless as to the advantages
   and disadvantages of this approach).
2. Implementing access rights and privileges in Oracle database(each
   user would be an Oracle account) and use the virtual private
   database, caching, secure roles.... from a performance stand point
   this is the best approach. Security! well I know it is good but I am
   afraid I am missing good things not implementing it in PHP.

I did some research on the net but in vain(I scratched my head a lot). I am new to PHP but I have good knowledge about Oracle.
Any suggestions, Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As you say you're going to have 1000s of users, i assume your software is going to be used in a big company, which probably means there's not *one* IT department, but several of them - one providing managed basic hardware (OS level but no applications), another managing databases, and a third one putting it all together (hardware+os, database, application) and providing the managed application as a service for the end user. My decision might be heavily influenced by working for such a department for over 10 years now.

I've seen one application that used the "one database user per OS user" approach (VPM by Dassault Systems, an attachment to the Catia V4 CAD system - and it's a horror to maintain. You want to have your permissions in *ONE* place, not several. Possibly you have a nice GUI to change them, but when your user calls you saying "i can't do X", and your GUI says he should be able to do X, it's simply too tedious to search everywhere. We've had cases where views didn't have the access roles they should have, views were wrongly defined, users had permissions on some tables but not all of them, all that stuff.

Additionally, our database department has - at the moment - about 600 "databases" that are used by diffent departments. So they are running about 20 real "databases" on several clusters, and they have implemented quite a rigid scheme of database names and corresponding user names. Each database has a base name XXX, with XXX_A the user name DDL statements, and XXX_U for DML. Applications may ONLY use XXX_U, which also means applications may not do DDL. This allows the database admins, in case of load issues on the cluster, to move an entire schema, including all users, roles and tables, to a different instance on a different cluster easily, without knowing too much about the individual databases. Of course, our VPM database doesn't fit into that schema, so we had to argue with the DB people a lot - and our monthly charge by the DB department is much higher than normal, because they have much more trouble administrating it.

Bottom line: Don't expect you can do whatever you want within your database. In a large company, with a department managing the databases, you will have restrictions what your application is allowed to do and what it isn't.

Also, your management might, at one time, decide they want to move to a different database system like DB2 for political reasons. This has much less to do with technical advantages than with who's invited whom to golf. You might, at one time, be asked if your system could be moved to a different database, by people you don't want to say "no" to. I wouldn't want to be dependent on too specific oracle features in this case.

Also keep in mind that requirements change over time, and there might be new, more granular, requirements in a while. This strongly favours doing the permission stuff in software, because it's much easier to add another column to a permission table that specifies something new, instead of having to implement something new in a database permission structure that just isn't meant to handle this kind of thing.

If you were developing a native application that runs on individual users' PCs, using only one oracle account might be a big security hole. But as you're using PHP, it's only the server that's communicating with the DB, so noone can extract login information from userspace anyways.

In my opinion, create an api for permission management first. Do not use oracle users, groups and roles for that; instead, manage your permissions in some SQL tables. Create an api (a collection of `check_if_user_X_may_do_Y` functions), possibly in pl/sql if you feel more comfortable there, better in PHP if you want to be portable. Build your application on this API. It might be more dev work at the start, but will result (imho) in much less administration work later.

Comment: I appreciate your help Guntram Blohm! you opened my eyes on some other aspects I was not aware of. You might want to read my comment to symcbean. I might also add that audit is a lot easier to manage in Oracle database for oracle accounts (though you can use other criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Although Guntram makes some very salient points, he has missed what I consider to be fairly essential considerations:

1) you describe a 3 tier model of authorization which the Oracle permissions model does not accomodate (although it is possible to represent this as a 2-tier model but at the cost of creating work and complexity).

2) using the user supplied credentials to authenticate against the database pretty much precludes the use of persistent database connections - which is rather important when your connection setup time is as expensive as it is with Oracle.

By all means store the representation of the groups/sub-groups/users/permissions in the database but not as Oracle users. But use a single (or small number) of oracle accounts for the access from PHP to the DBMS.

If you want to implement strong security, then you should also store mappings between sessions ids and users (not necessarily the session data itself) in the database, allow no direct access from the designated Oracle accounts to the data - only via stored procedures - and pass the session id as an authentication token to the stored procedure and validate it there (but note that this will be rather expensive if you are using trivial ORM).

Comment: I appreciate your help symcbean! but for your suggestions, 1) it is fairly easy to set up a virtual private database, (based on oracle accounts or session data), for dml on tables. 2) starting from 11gr1 one can use DRCP (Database Resident Connection Pooling) for applications that can't pool connections. just two statement to configure it.